# In Chef how do I detect if chef is running on a Mac?

Tags: chef-infra

In my cookbooks, how should I check if the chef recipe is being provisioned onto a Macintosh machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution is to use a [platform_family](http://docs.opscode.com/dsl_recipe_method_platform_family.html) check. Will work for both OS X and OS X server (Source [OHAI-345](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/OHAI-345)).

```
cookbook_file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
  source "nginx.conf"
  not_if platform_family?("mac_os_x")
end
```

An even better solution would be to let chef do all the work. Use a single [cookbook_file](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_files.html) declaration:

```
cookbook_file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
  source "nginx.conf"
end
```

And ship the platform specific files with your cookbook:

- mycookbook/files/default/nginx.conf
- mycookbook/files/mac_os_x/nginx.conf
- mycookbook/files/ubuntu/nginx.conf
- ..

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
node[:platform] == "mac_os_x"
```

to check.

You can do a `not_if` block like this:

```
cookbook_file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
     source "nginx.conf"
     not_if { node[:platform] == "mac_os_x" }
end
```